# react-native-vactor-icon is causing error after update react native 0.72

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease' (type 'AndroidLintAnalysisTask').

  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\React-Projects\English-Muni\android\app\build\intermediates\ReactNativeVectorIcons'.

    Reason: Task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease' uses this output
    of task ':app:copyReactNativeVectorIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Declare task ':app:copyReactNativeVectorIconFonts' as an input of ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease'.
    2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:copyReactNativeVectorIconFonts' from ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease' using Task#dependsOn.
    3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:copyReactNativeVectorIconFonts' from ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease' using Task#mustRunAfter.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

**Here is the app/build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"


import com.android.build.OutputFile


android {
  ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

  namespace "com.englishmuni"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.englishmuni"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 36
    versionName "1.0.32"
    buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", 
    isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
   }

     }

dependencies {

  implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform- 
android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the simpler patch that works for variants on RN 0.72,for vector icons. You have to replace these lines in `/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle`

```kotlin
afterEvaluate {
     .
     .
     .
     android.applicationVariants.all { def variant ->
        def targetName = variant.name.capitalize()
        def lintVitalAnalyzeTask = tasks.findByName("lintVitalAnalyze${targetName}")
            if (lintVitalAnalyzeTask) {
                lintVitalAnalyzeTask.dependsOn(fontCopyTask)
            }
        def generateAssetsTask = tasks.findByName("generate${targetName}Assets")
        generateAssetsTask.dependsOn(fontCopyTask)
    }
```

then patch the package. `npx patch-package react-native-vector-icons`

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in react-native-vector-icons v10.0.0. See the relevant [Github issue here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1516).

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided above worked for me after looking for possible solution and spending hours.
I added below lines in /node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle:

```
afterEvaluate {
 .
 .
 .
 android.applicationVariants.all { def variant ->
    def targetName = variant.name.capitalize()
    def lintVitalAnalyzeTask = tasks.findByName("lintVitalAnalyze${targetName}")
        if (lintVitalAnalyzeTask) {
            lintVitalAnalyzeTask.dependsOn(fontCopyTask)
        }
    def generateAssetsTask = tasks.findByName("generate${targetName}Assets")
    generateAssetsTask.dependsOn(fontCopyTask)
}
```

and then I tried **npx patch-package react-native-vector-icons** in terminal:

and **cd android**
**./gradlew assembleRelease**
and Boom! it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now resolved from version 10.0.0 as noted https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/releases/tag/v10.0.0.